# How to open two spinners at a time in android?

Tags: android, adapter, android-spinner

I know how to work with single spinner. I'am populating one spinner with kilograms and other with grams.  I have to open two spinners at a time (one beside other) on click of a button/view. User should be able to scroll through items of spinners individually and select kilograms & grams at one shot. How can i do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use a custom `View` for that.  Have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) project.  I use it in my current project, and it's excellent.